# Is it possible to set dynamic download delay in scrapy?

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, delay

I know that a constant delay can be set in

```
settings.py
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2
```

however, if I set the delay to 2s it is not efficient enough. If I set the DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.

The crawler is able to crawl about 10 pages. after that, the target page will return something like " you are requesting too frequently ".

What I want to do is the keep the download_delay to 0. once the "requesting too frequently" msg is found in the html. it change the delay to 2s. After a while it switch back to zero.

is there any module can do this? or any other better idea to handle such case?

Update:
I found that is a extension call [AutoThrottle](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html)
but is it able to customize some logic like this??

```
if (requesting too frequently) is found
    increase the DOWNLOAD_DELAY
```

Comment: Is exactly what Autothrottle does; you can also set its limits.

Answer (score 0):

If right after you get anti-spider page, then in 2 seconds you can get data page, then what you are asking probably requires writing a downloader middleware
that checks for anti-spider page, reset all scheduled requests to a renew-queue, start a looping call when spider is idle to get request from the renew-queue, (the looping interval is your hack for a new download delay), and try to decide when the download delay is not necessary again (requires some tests), then stop the looping and reschedule all the requests in renew-queue to scrapy scheduler.  You will need to use redis queue in case of distributed crawl.

With download delay set to 0, in my experience throughput can go easily above 1000 items/min.  If anti-spider page pops up after 10 responses, then it is not worth the effort.

Instead maybe you can try to find out how fast does your target server allow, may be 1.5s, 1s, 0.7s, 0.5s etc.  Then maybe redesign your product takes into consideration the throughput your crawler can achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Auto Throttle extension](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html) now. It is turned off by default. You can add these parameters in your project's settings.py file to enable it.

```
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 300
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = True
```

Answer (score -4):

Yes, You can use the time module to set the dynamic delay.

```
import time

for i in range(10):
   *** Operations 1****
   time.sleep( i )
   *** Operations 2****
```

Now you can see the delay between Operations 1 and Operations 2.

Note:

the variable 'i' is in the form of seconds.

Comment: sleep doesn't work on scrapy, it uses a asyc api built with twisted.